# How to make R package xgboost parallel in OS X with OpenMP compilation?

Tags: r, macos, xgboost

I am using xgb.cv and xgboost in R. However, it is not working as parallel

My example code as follow

```
library(xgboost)
library(parallel)
param <- list("objective" = "reg:logistic"
          , "eval_metric" = "logloss"
          ,"nthread" = 8
          ,"bst:eta" = .025
          ,"bst:max_depth" = 3
          ,"lambda" = 1
          ,"lambda_bias" = 0
          ,"alpha" = .8
          ,"min_child_weight" = 3
          ,"subsample" = .9
          ,"colsample_bytree" = .6)
bst.cv3 = xgb.cv(param=param, data = x, label = y,
             nfold = 3, nrounds=cv.nround, missing = NA
             ,prediction = TRUE)
```

However, above code is not working. What I have to do to make them parallel?

There is thing I found this on xgboost website and github

1. https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/build.md#building-on-osx
2. https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/276

However, I am not able to run

```
brew install clang-omp
```

or

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

with sudo also not working
Thanks

Comment: It does not work like you get an error, or it doesn't work using 8 cores?  Are you on Mac or Windows?

Comment: I am using mac computer

Comment: See this (very similar) [question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942893/how-to-install-xgboost-on-osx-with-multi-threading/40943005#40943005)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previously selected answer unfortunately is now outdated. The `clang-omp` package is no longer available in homebrew. So here's what worked for me.

First, at the shell:

```
brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
```

Then, create the file `~/.R/Makevars` with the following contents, making sure to update the paths so they correctly reflect the gcc version homebrew installed:

```
CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/gcc-6
CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/g++-6
SHLIB_CXXLD=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/g++-6
FC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/gfortran-6
F77=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/gfortran-6
MAKE=make -j8

SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS=-fopenmp
```

Finally, restart R or RStudio and re-install the packages from source.

Wrote a small blog post about this at https://asieira.github.io/using-openmp-with-r-packages-in-os-x.html, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I figured this out.

create a new file `vi ~/.R/Makevars`
and drop this in

```
CC=clang-omp
CXX=clang-omp++
CXX1X=clang-omp++
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS=-fopenmp
```

then install with
`install.packages("xgboost", repos="http://dmlc.ml/drat/", type = "source")`

If that didn't work use brew to install clang and gcc

`brew reinstall clang-omp`

then run the code above.

Comment: The package is no longer available at homebrew since the project has been migrated to llvm.org.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in a recent xgboost commit [1]

[1] https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/commit/d754ce7dc19e0d7c7465999d464e13f9bf21b40d