# Trouble installing xgboost (with multi-thread option) on OSX

Tags: r, macos, xgboost

Forgive me for the dumb question.. I just went through the installation process documented [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-osx).  I guessed what to do in some places where the docs weren't clear and at the ended up with a log full of cryptic text and warnings, but no errors.

Where I'm stuck/confused is that R can't find xgboost now. It's like I missed a step to point R where xgboost is (but I've never installed a package in this way). xgboost doesn't show in my list of packages in RStudio and `library("xgboost")` gives an error.  Keep in mind the xgboost directory I generated from doing `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost` just got dropped into "/Users/Ben/".  Is this right?  Should I have first `cd`'ed somewhere else before my `git clone`?

Note that I'm on Mac OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Have you tried installing using homebrew? if not check this site out:https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_on_Mac_OSX?lang=en

Comment: also checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709524/how-to-make-r-package-xgboost-parallel-in-os-x-with-openmp-compilation

Comment: Sounds like I just need to install the package from source.  Will give it a try in the morning as it's late here.  Very helpful, Cyrus.  Thanks!

Comment: good luck, seems like a great tool for machine learning!