# How to install XGBoost on OSX with multi-threading

Tags: c++, r, macos, xgboost

I'm trying to install xgboost on my mac (osx 10.12.1) following the guide [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-osx) but I'm running into some issues.

---

### Step1

> Obtain gcc-6.x.x with openmp support by `brew install gcc --without-multilib`

**Terminal**

```
Ben$ brew install gcc --without-multilib
Error: gcc-5.3.0 already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink gcc`

Ben$ brew unlink gcc
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0... 1288 symlinks removed

Ben$ brew install gcc --without-multilib
[26 minutes later]
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0: 1,358 files, 238.3M, built in 26 minutes 20 seconds
```

---

### Step2

> Clone the repository `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost`

**Terminal**

```
Ben$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
Cloning into 'xgboost'...
remote: Counting objects: 18754, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Total 18754 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 18733
Receiving objects: 100% (18754/18754), 6.23 MiB | 3.74 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11347/11347), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule 'dmlc-core' (https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core) registered for path 'dmlc-core'
Submodule 'rabit' (https://github.com/dmlc/rabit) registered for path 'rabit'
Cloning into '/Users/Ben/xgboost/dmlc-core'...
Cloning into '/Users/Ben/xgboost/rabit'...
Submodule path 'dmlc-core': checked out 'f35f14f30835af238257b979cc1fac3e41ff3291'
Submodule path 'rabit': checked out 'a9a2a69dc1144180a43f7d2d1097264482be7817'
```

---

### Step3

> build using the following commands `cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4`
>
> NOTE: If you use OSX El Capitan, brew installs gcc the latest version gcc-6. So you may need to modify Makefile#L46 and change gcc-5 to gcc-6. After that change gcc-5/g++-5 to gcc-6/g++-6 in make/config.mk then build using the following commands

Hmmm. Not entirely sure what to do here. I see a file called "Makefile" inside `xgboost/`. Inside it I see a lot of stuff I don't understand, but these lines look relevant

*Makefile (snippet)*

```
# on Mac OS X, force brew gcc-6, since the Xcode c++ fails anyway
# it is useful for pip install compiling-on-the-fly
OS := $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
export CC = $(if $(shell which gcc-6),gcc-6,$(if $(shell which gcc-mp-6), gcc-mp-6, clang))
export CXX = $(if $(shell which g++-6),g++-6,$(if $(shell which g++-mp-6),g++-mp-6, clang++))
endif
```

Going to ignore this and move on...

**Terminal**

```
Ben$ cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
[Tons of log output. Appears to finish succesfully]
...
g++-6 -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -shared -o lib/libxgboost.so build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a -pthread -lm  -fopenmp
```

---

### Step4 (instructions [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#r-package-installation)?)

> If you would like to use the latest xgboost version and already
>   compiled xgboost, use `library(devtools); install('xgboost/R-package')`
>   to install manually xgboost package (change the path accordingly to
>   where you compiled xgboost).

**New R session**

```
library(devtools)
install("/Users/Ben/xgboost/R-package")

Installing xgboost
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/Users/Ben/xgboost/R-package' --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘xgboost’ ...
** libs
g++-5 -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../..//include -I../..//dmlc-core/include -I../..//rabit/include -I../../ -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=1 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c xgboost_R.cc -o xgboost_R.o
make: g++-5: No such file or directory
make: *** [xgboost_R.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xgboost’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/xgboost’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/xgboost’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Fail :(  Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated Solution

As of March 2019, R version 3.5.3, xgboost version 0.82.0.1, things have changed since my old answer. The following steps are based on the [installation guide here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html), but differ slightly.

1. `brew install cmake` or `brew upgrade cmake` (`cmake --version` shows 3.14.0 for me)
2. `brew install gcc` or `brew upgrade gcc` (Note the version of gcc that gets installed. It should be located in `/usr/local/bin`. I get gcc 8.3.0 (`gcc-8 --version`))
3. `cd some/unimportant/directory`
4. `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost`
5. `cd xgboost/`
6. `mkdir build`
7. `cd build`
8. `CC=gcc-8 CXX=g++-8 cmake .. -DR_LIB=ON`
9. `make -j4`
10. `sudo make install`

Now restart/refresh RStudio and it should be installed

### Test in R

```
set.seed(222)
N <- 2*10^5
p <- 350
x <- matrix(rnorm(N  * p), ncol = p)
y <- rnorm(N)

system.time(mymodel <- xgboost(
  # nthread = 4,
  data = x,
  label = y, 
  nrounds = 5, 
  objective = "reg:linear", 
  tree_method = "exact",
  max_depth = 10,
  min_child_weight = 1, 
  eta = 1, 
  subsample = 0.66, 
  colsample_bytree = 0.33
))

# Tested on 2018 MPB, xgboost version 0.82.0.1, multi-threaded version
# nthread = default:   7.4 seconds (elapsed)
# nthread = 1:        24.0 seconds (elapsed)
# nthread = 2:        13.7 seconds (elapsed)
# nthread = 4:         7.5 seconds (elapsed)
```

---

## Old Answer

It's amazing how writing your question on StackOverflow often leads you directly to the answer. After spending hours on this, I figured out that I needed to change these three lines in `~/.R/Makevars`

```
CC=gcc-5
CXX=g++-5
CXX1X = g++-5
```

to

```
CC=gcc-6
CXX=g++-6
CXX1X = g++-6
```

Also, I ended up installing xgboost from the "drat" repo

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("xgboost", repos="http://dmlc.ml/drat/", type = "source")
```

Comment: Thanks - but I needed another addition: on my SLES machine I further needed to add `CPICFLAGS=-fPIC`,  `CXXPICFLAGS=-fPIC` and `CXX1PICFLAGS=-fPIC` to the Makevars.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is after your first(update gcc) and second(clone) steps, no need to build anything(they are for other languages like python)

3) update ~/.R/Makevars

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1136

[How to make R package xgboost parallel in OS X with OpenMP compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709524/how-to-make-r-package-xgboost-parallel-in-os-x-with-openmp-compilation)

4) from the clone xgboost/R-package/configure change `ac_pkg_openmp` to yes
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2503

5) in xgboost/R-package type `R CMD INSTALL .`
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#r-package-installation